# Edit adresses with regular expressions in R

Tags: regex, r

I'd like to edit the addresses of strings such as this example:

```
test = c("[Mavlyanova, Nadira G.] Uzbek Acad Sci, GA Mavlyanov Inst Seismol, Tashkent 700135, Uzbekistan; [Markovic, Slobodan B.] Univ Novi Sad, Fac Sci, Chair Phys Geog, Novi Sad 21000, Serbia; [Rowell, G.] Univ Adelaide, Sch Chem & Phys, Adelaide, SA 5005, Australia; [Katarzynski, K.] Nicholas Copernicus Univ, Torun Ctr Astron, PL-87100 Torun, Poland; [Ansari, Z.; Boettcher, M.; Manschwetus, B.; Rottke, H.; Sandner, W.] Max Born Inst, D-12489 Berlin, Germany; [Milosevic, D. B.] Univ Sarajevo, Fac Sci, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia & Herceg")
```

I'd like to get only the country names. This is what I tried so far:

```
> testa <- gsub("\\[.*?\\] ", "", test) #remove square brackets  
> testa <- strsplit(testa, ";", fixed = TRUE) #split adresses  
> testa <- sapply(testa, function(x) gsub("^.*, ([A-Za-z ]*)$", "\\1", x)) #keep only what's after last comma  
> testa <- gsub("^ | $", "", testa) #remove spaces  
> testa  
     [,1]  
[1,] "Uzbekistan"  
[2,] "Serbia"  
[3,] "Australia"  
[4,] "Poland"  
[5,] "Germany"  
[6,] "Univ Sarajevo, Fac Sci, Sarajevo 71000, Bosnia & Herceg"
```

So this doesn't work for the last address, unfortunately. I'd like to get the following output instead:

```
> testa  
     [,1]                                                       
[1,] "Uzbekistan"  
[2,] "Serbia"  
[3,] "Australia"  
[4,] "Poland"  
[5,] "Germany"  
[6,] "Bosnia & Herceg"
```

My questions are:

- What's the error in my sapply-function which prevents it from correctly working with the last address as well?
- How can I improve it in order to achieve the correct output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the “everything after the last comma” part of your code uses `[A-Za-z ]` as the only valid characters after that. This set does not include `&`, hence the replacement isn't performed on the last address. Perhaps you should use `[^,]` to denote “Anything but a comma” instead.

Comment: Nice explanation.  I think you need `,perl=TRUE` to use negation, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, @MvG! I hadn't thought of that before. I added "&" to the function which works perfectly now.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just work backwards?

```
testa <- gsub("\\[.*?\\] ", "", test)
testa <- strsplit(testa, ";", fixed = TRUE)
# Remaining steps in question are unnecessary with the solution below

> sub(".+, ([A-Za-z& ]+)$","\\1",testa[[1]])
[1] "Uzbekistan"      "Serbia"          "Australia"       "Poland"          "Germany"         "Bosnia & Herceg"
```

Answer (score 1):

There's already some better answers here but I had worked through this problem so I thought I'd still post:

```
y <- unlist(strsplit(test, "\\["))
y <- y[y!=""]
z <- sapply(y, function(x) strsplit(x, ","))
lens <- sapply(z, length)
a <- sapply(seq_along(z), function(i) z[[i]][lens[i]])
a <- gsub(";", "", a)
Trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
Trim(a)
```

Comment: Just looked up `\s`.  Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner using `strapplyc` (or `strapply` would work too but `strapplyc` is faster here) in the gsubfn package.  First append a `";"` to `test` and then search for a `[` (using the regexp `"\\["`) followed by a string of any characters except `[` (using the regexp `"[^[]+"`) followed by a comma and space (`", "`) followed by any sequence of characters other than comma, semicolon or `[` (using the regexp `"([^,;[]+)"`) followed by a semicolon (`;`) and return only the part within parentheses:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapplyc(paste0(test, ";"), "\\[[^[]+, ([^,;[]+);", simplify = TRUE)
     [,1]             
[1,] "Uzbekistan"     
[2,] "Serbia"         
[3,] "Australia"      
[4,] "Poland"         
[5,] "Germany"        
[6,] "Bosnia & Herceg"
```